# How to get object id from post?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm working with the Facebook API using the PHP SDK.

I'm trying to loop through a user's posts and then loop through the comments on that post.

I'm looping through the posts fine. But when I go to loop through the comments, I need an object id. I've learned this is different than the post id. I'm confused though, because in my post object i only have a post id, there is no object it. How/where do I get this object id?

```
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/posts');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

        foreach ($graphObject['data'] as $post) {  
            echo $post->message;
            $postId = $post->id;
            $commentsRequest = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', "/$postId/comments");
            $commentsResponse = $commentsRequest->execute();
            $commentsGraphObject = $commentsResponse->getGraphObject()->asArray();
            // $commentsGraphObject is an empty array here because I am passing the post id and not the object id, which I don't know where to get.
            foreach ($commentsGraphObject['data'] as $comment) {
                echo $comment->message;
            }       
        }
```

Comment: I see now that that post id contains my scoped user id, which I believe is why it's not returning any comments.

Comment: Figured it out, apparently I needed the "read_stream" permission. I figured I would just need "user_posts".

Comment: Corey, I'm curious as to what you experienced. Technically user_posts is all you need now to get the user's posts. Would you mind pasting here a Graph API session where you can reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "object_id" field available 
Ex: /posts/?fields=object_id

you can find more info in 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/post